# extending a class with special overload

Tags: php, operator-overloading

I what to basically extend a class and overload a function while still calling the original function in the overloaded function. Let me post me code first before I further explain.

```
class specList
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->list = array();
    }

    public function add($item)
    {
        $this->list[] = $item;
    }

    public function display()
    {
         /*  
          *  for simplicity sake lets assume I have a function ul($list) that 
          *  builds a properly formatted <ul> with each item contained in a <li>.
          */
         return ul($this->list);
    }
}

class wrappedList extends specList
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function display()
    {
        $return = '<div class="panel">';
        $return .= //I need some way to call the parents display() function
        return $return.'</div>';
    }
}
```

I know this seems a really complex way of adding such a simple feature. This is a watered down version of my code to provide a simple example to explain my problem. I need to be able to use the same name to overload to function but add a beginning and end set of code to the extended class. Is there anyway to accomplish this? I don't know where else to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent::display()`. See [the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

For example:

```
class wrappedList extends specList
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function display()
    {
        $return = '<div class="panel">';
        $return .= parent::display();
        return $return.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: ugh.. I hate when answers are right in front of me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer ;-).

Answer (score 0):

To call the parent function, you can use `parent::display()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily re-define a function and call the parent format as well.

```
class Food {

    public function eat()    {
        echo "eating food!";
    }
}

class Banana extends Food {

    public function eat() {
        parent::eat();
        echo "eating banana";
    }
}

$banana = new Banana();
$banana->eat();
```